# Why is my program not waiting for input?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get user input and validate it using regular expressions. However, when I run the program, it doesn't seem to be waiting to receive any additional user input. Instead, I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Any help on what is happening would be great!

Here is my code:

```
//Retrieve name
System.out.println("What name would you like to search for? (Enter first name only without spaces)");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter first name only.");
    input.next();
}
String name = input.next();
System.out.println("You gave me as input the name:" + name);
}
```

Comment: I'm able to run this without any issues. What sort of input are you entering?

Comment: why is there a +sign after the [A-Za-z] ?

Comment: @ClydeD'Cruz It's a regex metacharacter that means "1 or more of the preceding".

Comment: You were asking a totally different question previously (for which my answer provided a solution). If you want to ask another question, do not edit your original question. Accept the answer and post a new question ! Otherwise you will be editing your initial post with different questions every time you feel so, which makes no sense at SO !

Comment: Ok good. It will also increase visibility of your new question so it is better for you also (I just saw that you totally changed your question by accident) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine. Try this as a fully working class (*save it as* `myInput.java`, then *compile it* using `javac myInput.java` , then *run it using* `java myInput`):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class myInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Retrieve name
    System.out.println("What name would you like to search for? (Enter first name only without spaces)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter first name only.");
        input.next();
    }
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("You gave me as input the name:" + name);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT (I first give an invalid input (test1) and then a valid is printed correctly (test)):

```
test1
Invalid entry. Please enter first name only.
test
You gave me as input the name:test
```